# Removing BOM from a UTF-8 MySQL/MariaDB search

Tags: php, mysql, regex, mysqli, mariadb

I'm importing UTF-8 CSV data to MariaDB/MySQL. Since I'm using a shared server, my hosting company doesn't let me use LOAD DATA INFILE, so I need to do it the old fashioned way. I want to do some validations before data loading and one of the checks is to see whether a column that is being loaded exists in the database.

**This used to work, except now after the file being loaded is utf8 it doesn't (has BOM in the beginning):**

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM magic_products '$value';
```

**This does NOT work, but you see what I'm looking for:**

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM magic_products LIKE CONVERT('$value' USING utf8);
```

An other way to go would be to use a regexp to get rid of the UTF8 Byte Order Mark (ï»¿) -sequence.

Comment: Do you import the CSV into the database by hand?

Comment: I import the CSV (made with Excel, saved as UTF-8) with a PHP script.

Comment: which encoding were CSV written in before?

Comment: I used normal MS-DOS CSV (saved in Excel), but as that did not support scandinavian characters I needed to move to UTF-8 CSV.

Comment: can you paste the PHP code you use to read your CSV?

Comment: Then simply add a line of PHP code to remove the BOM.